# Conversion Matlab to Python labels

Tags: python, matlab, type-conversion

I am writing part of code in Matlab and then proceed into python. In Matlab I have labels like

```
labels=[1 2 49 49 50 50 51];
```

and in Python I need to load that to have`labels=['1','2','49','49','50','50','51']

How?I tried 
    `o1 = scipy.io.loadmat('labels.mat')
    labels1=np.array(o1['labels'])`
but I get

```
[[array([[1]], dtype=uint8) array([[1]], dtype=uint8)
  array([[1]], dtype=uint8) array([[2]], dtype=uint8)
  array([[2]], dtype=uint8) array([[2]], dtype=uint8)
  array([[49]], dtype=uint8) array([[49]], dtype=uint8)
  array([[49]], dtype=uint8) array([[50]], dtype=uint8)
  array([[50]], dtype=uint8) array([[50]], dtype=uint8)
  array([[51]], dtype=uint8) array([[51]], dtype=uint8)
  array([[51]], dtype=uint8) array([[52]], dtype=uint8)
  array([[52]], dtype=uint8) array([[52]], dtype=uint8)
  array([[53]], dtype=uint8) array([[53]], dtype=uint8)
  array([[53]], dtype=uint8) array([[54]], dtype=uint8)
  array([[54]], dtype=uint8) array([[54]], dtype=uint8)]]
```

I need this because those are labels for next step :

```
Y=pdist(X, 'correlation')
Z=hierarchy.linkage(Y, method='complete', metric='correlation')
row_dendr = hierarchy.dendrogram(Z, labels=labels1)
```

Can I save it in Matlab somehow else to make it easy?Those labels I make in loop so it is a big vector.
If I type onlu print o1 I get:

```
{'__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: PCWIN64, Created on: Fri May      13 20:11:14 2016', '__version__': '1.0', 'labels': array([[array([[1]],     dtype=uint8), array([[1]], dtype=uint8),
    array([[1]], dtype=uint8), array([[2]], dtype=uint8),
    array([[2]], dtype=uint8), array([[2]], dtype=uint8),
    array([[49]], dtype=uint8), array([[49]], dtype=uint8),
    array([[49]], dtype=uint8), array([[50]], dtype=uint8),
    array([[50]], dtype=uint8), array([[50]], dtype=uint8),
    array([[51]], dtype=uint8), array([[51]], dtype=uint8),
    array([[51]], dtype=uint8), array([[52]], dtype=uint8),
    array([[52]], dtype=uint8), array([[52]], dtype=uint8),
    array([[53]], dtype=uint8), array([[53]], dtype=uint8),
    array([[53]], dtype=uint8), array([[54]], dtype=uint8),
    array([[54]], dtype=uint8), array([[54]], dtype=uint8)]], dtype=object), '__globals__': []}
```

Comment: I've never used the scipy.io.loadmat function, but looking at the documentation, it returns a dictionary.  What do you get if you type 'print o1'? If it is indeed returning a dictionary, I think you may be able to just pull out the data from the values - it looks like you just want a list.

Comment: It looks like your labels that you put into matlab don't match what you're reading into python...are you sure those labels reflect what you're reading in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens if you define labels like this and run the following code:

```
from itertools import chain
labels1=o1['labels']
list(chain(*labels1))
```